# React-Router 4 default route content displays on all other components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning react and trying to set up routes with react-router-dom. All the routes are working except the default route. The content of the default route component displays on all other components when i navigate to their routes.
here is the code and the output below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import One from './one';
import Two from './two';
import Three from './three';
import FourOFour from './404';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>
        <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
        <Route path="/Three" component={Three}></Route>
        <Route path="*" component={FourOFour}></Route>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>, 
document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap in a `<Switch>` ?

Comment: I don't understand. I'm new to react

Comment: see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch and the example on the right - it will pick the first match.

Comment: It worked, i just had to import Switch from react-router-dom. Thank you. Please can you provide me with a link to a tutorial apart from the documentation for react 16 so i can learn from there. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

First thing you need to make use of `<Switch>` and wrap it around your `<Routes>`

As described in [Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In
>   contrast, every  that matches the location renders inclusively.

Firstly to make sure import Switch in your file like this:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

  <Switch>
    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}></Route>
    <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>
    <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
    <Route path="/Three" component={Three}></Route>
    <Route path="*" component={FourOFour}></Route>
  <Switch>
```

So your code should be like :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'; // Note this extra line
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import One from './one';
import Two from './two';
import Three from './three';
import FourOFour from './404';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch> // Note this extra Line
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>
        <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
        <Route path="/Three" component={Three}></Route>
        <Route path="*" component={FourOFour}></Route>
  <Switch>
</BrowserRouter>, 
document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

You can read more about `<Switch >` [Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Comment: Oh, the sweet karma! Since you are doing 10s of edits, remove the `<div>` wrap and just leave the `<Switch>` :)

Comment: Literally unusable with the extra `<div>` tag...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in right direction Dimitar Christoff , finally fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `Routes` in a [`Switch`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md). A `Switch` will match the first `Route` and return it. If you don't use a switch, like you've done here, it will render out each route that matches the current path.

Change it to:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App}></Route>
        <Route path="/One" component={One}></Route>
        <Route path="/Two" component={Two}></Route>
        <Route path="/Three" component={Three}></Route>
        <Route path="*" component={FourOFour}></Route>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Returns an error Switch is not defined

Comment: @DavidEssien You need to import `Switch` at the top of your component. `import { Switch } from react-router-dom;`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because all the `Route`s components that match the location will render. In order to render a single route (first match) you need to wrap your routes in a `Switch` component.

---

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/One" component={One} />
            <Route path="/Two" component={Two} />
            <Route path="/Three" component={Three} />
            <Route component={FourOFour} />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

---

> `<Route>` responsibility is to render some UI when a location matches the route's path.
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

Read more about [React-Router's Switch](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

Comment: I mean this is the correct answer, just really low effort. No code examples or links to resources.

Comment: I just  wanted to answer quickly to provide a fast hint/solution.